# Filling in a small detail in Evans' PDE (chap 6 - second-order elliptic equations)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading Evans' PDE book. There's a tiny detail in one of his proofs that I'm not understanding. The proof in question is Theorem 1, chapter 6.3.1, on interior regularity of second-order elliptic equations. (My question is very very specific, I hope that's ok. In the second edition, it's on pg330, 3/4th of the way down the page.)

\begin{align*}
\int_U |v|^2 dx &\leq C \int_U |D(\zeta^2 D^h_ku)|^2 dx  \\
&\leq C \int_W |D^h_ku|^2 + \zeta^2 |D^h_k Du|^2 dx \\
&\leq C \int_U |Du|^2 + \zeta^2 |D_h^kDu|^2 dx
\end{align*}

where the notation $D^h_k$ denotes the difference quotient, $\zeta$ is a cutoff function for $V \subset\subset W \subset\subset U$, and $v$ is defined as $v:=-D_k^{-h}(\zeta^2D_k^hu)$.

First inequality is by a bound on difference quotients that was already proven.

I am specifically confused about how to go from the first line down to the second line. I think:

\begin{align*}
|D(\zeta^2D_k^hu)| &= |2\zeta D\zeta \cdot D_k^hu + \zeta^2D_k^h Du| \\
&= |2\zeta D\zeta||D^h_ku| + \zeta^2|D_k^hDu|
\end{align*}

but proceeding this way, I'll end up with extra terms and I'm not sure what to do with them. Hint please?

Comment: It is a inequality in the place of the second equality.

Comment: It's worth remembering that $C$ need not be the same number in every line. Each inequality $\dots\le C\dots$ is a statement that the left side is bounded by the right side, times some constant. (The constant should really be constant, not something that depends on $u$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use three things:

I - $|2\zeta D\zeta||D_k^h u|+\zeta^2|D_k^h Du|\leq 2\|\zeta\|_\infty \| D\zeta\|_\infty|D_k^h u|+\zeta^2|D_k^h Du|\leq C(|D_k^h u|+\zeta^2|D_k^h Du|)$

II - $(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

III - $\zeta^4\leq \zeta^2$

Comment: Ah ok I see, I thought the bound would be a tighter one, but this makes sense. Thanks!